# Azure & Github actions: Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": denied: denied

Tags: azure-devops, github-actions

I've searched other questions with the same error message on here and none of them mention Azure.
I am using the Azure Deployment center for deployment which seems to log in to your github account and do everything for you but I still get this error "build
Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": denied: denied" when the Github actions workflow runs.

Below is the workflow file.
One thought I had, my repo are my source files together with my docker file. Is it expecting a docker image file instead?

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy container app to Azure Web App - aeris-qai

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

    - name: Log in to registry
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        registry: https://ghcr.io/
        username: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_ContainerUsername_XXX }}
        password: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_ContainerPassword_XXX }}

    - name: Build and push container image to registry
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
      with:
        push: true
        tags: ghcr.io/${{ secrets.AzureAppService_ContainerUsername_XXX }}/mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticsite:${{ github.sha }}
        file: ./Dockerfile

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'XXXX'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfileXXX }}
        images: 'ghcr.io/${{ secrets.AzureAppService_ContainerUsername_XXX }}/mcr.microsoft.com/appsvc/staticsite:${{ github.sha }}'
```

What did you try: I ran the workflow
And what were you expecting?: I was expecting it the deployment to succeed
What actually resulted: Error response from daemon: Get "https://ghcr.io/v2/": denied: denied

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution in this case was to set up the step of creating a Docker image from your Dockerfile within Github first. Something that is not made clear in the Azure documentation.

To do this go to your Github repo > Actions and then on the left there will be a button for creating a new workflow. This should then give you an option for generating a Docker image. Just stick to the defaults and hit ok.